# Check if file is accessible from UWP programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, filesystems

Given a file location from a file chooser/picker. How to check if the UWP have the access to the file or not?

Comment: If you have been given a StorageFile by a file picker, you will always have access permission too it via that StorageFile object. You cannot store the file's path and try to access it again using the path directly without using the FutureAccessList API, however you can hold on to the StorageFile object as long as you want while the app is running.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake our scope is to develop the library where the file path is provided from the UI module. we cannot control UI permission so we need to guard and throw proper exception when provided paths are not accessible in our lib. Any way to check if file is readable/accessible given a path?

Comment: If this is UWP only, the library should accept StorageFile, which would guarantee access. Otherwise, your option is to stick try/catch around StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(...). Inelegant, but that's your choice.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake how can I accept StorageFile only? Any code snippet will be helpful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you try to open it and you don't have access, you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean, but here

```c
public FileStream TryOpen(string filePath, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess,FileShare fileShare,int maximumAttempts,int attemptWaitMS)
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    int attempts = 0;

    // Loop allow multiple attempts
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            fs = File.Open(filePath, fileMode, fileAccess, fileShare);

            //If we get here, the File.Open succeeded, so break out of the loop and return the FileStream
            break;
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            // IOExcception is thrown if the file is in use by another process.

            // Check the numbere of attempts to ensure no infinite loop
            attempts++;
            if (attempts > maximumAttempts)
            {
                // Too many attempts,cannot Open File, break and return null 
                fs = null;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Sleep before making another attempt
                Thread.Sleep(attemptWaitMS);

            }

        }

    }
    // Reutn the filestream, may be valid or null
    return fs;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a calling example

Comment: You are opening a filestream which nowhere closed!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the **broadFileSystemAccess** capability in Package.appxmanifest.
In addition, BroadFileSystemAccess is a restricted capability. Access is configurable in **Settings > Privacy > File system**.

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Then you could use the following simple sample to check if the file is readable and writable.

```
var file =await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                bool read = stream.CanRead;
                bool write = stream.CanWrite;
            }
```

Whether the file can be read depends on many factors. You should take this into consideration:

1.File may not exist
2.The file may be locked by another process

3.Someone/something can change access to files during the execution of the application

If an error occurs, the above code will raise an exception.

Comment: Is there any way to check without actually opening the stream, so far my concern is opening file is costly and I might need to check many files in directory. Thanks

Comment: You could try using [FileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-5.0) to get file property, then judge file status, such as Encrypted, ReadOnly.